# My callback is not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine-node

Here I'm trying to test my api but the callback function is not being called during the execution and return with no failures all the time.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const nconf = require('nconf');
const request = require('request');
var index = require('../index')
var querystring = require('querystring');


describe("Auth", function () {
console.log("Auth");

var form = {
    "email":"a@a.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "name":"aleem",
    "mobile":"12345678903",
    "country":"india",
    "state":"telangana",
    "city":"hyderabad"
}


var formData = querystring.stringify(form);

// Creating account with existing user data
it ("Returns statusText false", function (done) {
    var url = 'http://http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signup/';
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    request.post({ url: url, form: formData, headers: headers }, function (e, r, body) {
        // callback body
        console.log(r.statusCode+'ka');
        expect(r.statusText).toBe('false');
        done() ;
    });
});
});
```

During execution the callback function is not being called.

Comment: which callback specifically? describe? it? or request.post?

Comment: function in request.post

Comment: "it ("Returns statusText false", function () {" looks suspicious. Did you mean "if"?

Comment: No... It is a test case

Comment: @Kamalnrf Got it.

Comment: Even when I give correct response reference it is not working

Comment: Your test report is `exceeds timeout` or something like this. I saw that you did not call `done()` in your async test case.

Comment: It is the same when I call done also

Comment: I saw the duplicated `http://` on the URL. Its your actual code or just stackoverflow's version (lol)

Comment: The form submission doesn't look quite right. Get rid of the explicit `headers`, change `form: formData` to `form: form`, and get rid of the extra 'http://' in your URL. Additionally you can always set a `timeout` setting to the number of milliseconds you want to wait for the server to start sending a response.

Comment: `done` won't get called if the assertion right in front of it fails.